# Elasticsearch returns different results from same paginated query

Tags: pagination, elasticsearch

So I have been playing with paginating and am trying to resolve an issue where a result on page 64 will sometimes contain a hit on page 65.

If I execute this query

```
http://host:9200/index/_search?q=field:searchterm&size=1&from=100
```

I discover that every second query result is identical.

But if the pagination parameter has a lower value, all results are identical.

I've played with sorting, but the behavior is consistent.

Comment: try adding a preference param to the request parameter http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4//search-request-preference.html i'm  guessing this could be due to the bouncing result issue : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_search_options.html

Comment: Yes... that does resolve it! If I add &preference=primary_first or &preference=primary to the query string, the results are consistent. Not sure of the impact server side however.

Comment: @Grevase oh cool i'll move the comment to answer then

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a [preference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-preference) param to the request parameter.
I'm guessing this could be due to the [bouncing result issue](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_search_options.html).

For load balancing you could probably use preference parameter with a custom string such as username for the initial request.

Use the same custom string for subsequent pagination requests

Comment: This works great, it should be the accepted answer. I decided to use the GUID from the UserId as the `preference` parameter so that if a user bookmarked Page 3 of the search results, they will get the same results tomorrow (assuming no items changed).

Comment: Can someone explain why documents would have different scores on different shards? I don't think the documentation outlines why the shards have different scores to begin with.